# New Bitmap inside Background worker's body causes Memory Leak

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

I am drawing visualization for WaveIn recording data just for testing purposes, to see how correct is the data.
As you can see my mechanism is:

1) Some WaveIn thread (isn't included) pokes this Form through a delegate with audio buffer.

2) Background worker takes updated audio data, draw Bitmap 
and when finished, it reports the Progress and that handle from that native form thread just call WM_PAINT to update PictureBox background with new picture.

```
object localLock = new object();
Bitmap soundGraphImage;

private void soundGrapher_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
    while(are.WaitOne())
    {
        if (soundGrapher.CancellationPending) {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }
        if (audioData == null || audioData.Length == 0) continue;
        soundGraphImage = new Bitmap(graphWidth, graphHeight); <----- this one
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(soundGraphImage);
        lock (localLock)
        {
            #region Draw sound
            if (audioParms.nChannels > 1) { Vfw_MessageOut("More than 1 channel"); return; }
            int currentPos = 1;
            int accu = 0;
            int x = 1;
            int maxValue = 0;
            int baseY = soundGraph.Height / 2;

            int bytes = audioParms.wBitsPerSample / 8;
            int portion = (int)Math.Round(1.0 * audioData.Length / bytes / soundGraph.Width, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
            switch (bytes)
            {
                case 1: maxValue = Byte.MaxValue; break;
                case 2: maxValue = Int16.MaxValue; break;
                case 4: maxValue = Int32.MaxValue; break;
            }

            int halfValue = maxValue / 2;
            double coeff = multiPlyer * baseY / halfValue;
            for (int i = 0; i < audioData.Length; i = i + bytes)
            {
                if (currentPos == portion)
                {
                    accu = (int)(accu / portion);
                    g.DrawLine(Pens.White, new Point(x, baseY),
                        new Point(x, baseY - (int)(coeff * accu)));
                    currentPos = 1;
                    i = i - bytes;
                    x++;
                }
                else
                {
                    currentPos++;
                    switch (bytes)
                    {
                        case 1: accu += audioData[i] - halfValue; break;
                        case 2: accu += BitConverter.ToInt16(audioData, i); break;
                        case 4: accu += BitConverter.ToInt32(audioData, i); break;
                    }
                }
            }
            #endregion
        }
            g.Dispose();
            soundGrapher.ReportProgress(0);
    }
}
private void soundGrapher_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {

}
private void soundGrapher_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) {
    soundGraph.Invalidate();
}
```

The problem is in Bitmap.. this code causes memory leak.
Pls, help me to avoid this problem.

UPDATE

> Yes, the solution is easy, just to Dispose it.. I would get it, of
>   course, by myself, but I'm still having a bigger problem, and this
>   Bitmap was just on top of my stack when it came to the stage called
>   "stackoverflow".  But anyway it is fault of GC.. it should have
>   control such things. The callback is poking just once in a second.. I
>   have never been calling Dispose for each Bitmap in my previous
>   projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

> "Using" will destroy Bitmap out of its scope, but I still need it to
>   draw.

Oh dear...

You still have to `Dispose` it some how, as you are recreating it every time...

May i suggest.

```
soundGraphImage?.Dispose();
soundGraphImage = new Bitmap(graphWidth, graphHeight);
```

**Original**

Always use a `using` statement on anything that can support it, stick by that rule and (int this case) you will probably be right.

In this respect, you should at least be implementing a `using` on the following :-

```
using(var soundGraphImage = new Bitmap(graphWidth, graphHeight))
{
}
```

And on other objects, like the `Graphics` call just to be consistent

---

**Additional Resources**

[using statement (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)

> Provides a convenient syntax that ensures the correct use of
>   IDisposable objects.

[The using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#the-using-statement)

> The using statement obtains one or more resources, executes a
>   statement, and then disposes of the resource.

[IDisposable Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Provides a mechanism for releasing unmanaged resources.

Comment: "Using" will destroy Bitmap out of its scope, but I still need it to draw.

Comment: Hello Michael, Nullable Bitmap didn't work.. if (bitmap!= null... worked.. thank your )))